# Bootstrap Carousel, with choosen height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am trying to set a height on my carousel in bootstrap. If I set the height to 700px, the carousel looks like crap in responsive. So how do I fix this such that my carousel looks good on the desktop and smartphone etc.? What should be the appropriate height?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `vh and vw` for viewport height and width

```
.class{ 
  width: 50vw; 
  height: 50vh;       
}
```

> With vw/vh, we can size elements to be relative to the size of the
>   viewport. The vw/vh units are interesting in that 1 unit reflects
>   1/100th the width of the viewport. To make an element the full width
>   of the viewport, for example, you'd set it to width:100vw.

For more info **[refer](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units)** this link

1vw = 1% of viewport width
1vh = 1% of viewport height
1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

Comment: Agreed. Another solution could be media queries. Just throwing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use percent instead a fixed height, for instance 40%.